# Sitecore goals for Media Item don't affect engagement value

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

I use Sitecore 7.2 revision 140526 + DMS. I'm trying to assign goal to the media item (PDF). When I try to download this media item the goal get registered in the PageEvents table but Engagement Value of the visit does not change. I found following code inside StartTrackingProcessor:

```
Tracker.CurrentPage.OnCancel += (EventHandler)((obj, args) =>
{
    AcceptChangesArgs acceptChangesArgs = args as AcceptChangesArgs;
    if (acceptChangesArgs == null)
        return;
    VisitorDataSet.VisitsRow currentVisit = acceptChangesArgs.Visitor.CurrentVisit;
    if (currentVisit == null)
        return;

    Tracker.CurrentPage.RollBackValue(pageEventData, currentVisit);
});
```

This code prevents engagement value from increasing for the pages that have been cancelled somewhere in the pipeline. 
And then I found the code that cancel the page in the Sitecore.Analytics.RobotDetection.Media.MediaRequestEventHandler whech is enabled by Sitecore.Analytics.RobotDetection.config:

```
using (new ContextItemSwitcher(obj))
{
    try
    {
        this.StartTracking();
        VisitorDataSet.PagesRow previousPage = Tracker.CurrentVisit.PreviousPage;
        if (previousPage != null)
        {
            Guid pageId = previousPage.PageId;
            foreach (VisitorDataSet.PageEventsRow pageEventsRow in Enumerable.ToArray<VisitorDataSet.PageEventsRow>(Tracker.CurrentPage.PageEvents))
                pageEventsRow.PageId = pageId;


            Tracker.CurrentPage.Cancel();
        }
        this.EndTracking();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error("Media request analytics failed", ex, this.GetType());
    }
}
```

So this MediaRequestEventHandler cancels the page and therefore engagement value does not increase. I can override this behavior or disable RobotDetection.config but I want to understand the consequences and why it was done this way and I know there are recommendations not to disable Sitecore.Analytics.RobotDetection.config

So my question: what is the best way to assign points to the visit for media item download?

Comment: Is the request to the media file always cancelled or only when it is the first request of the session?  One of the improvements in 7.5 was to rework robot detection for media on a first visit.  So this may be something that Sitecore support could help you with.

Comment: @BenGolden From the code and from what I see when I test it looks like it always get cancelled.

Comment: Just to confirm, do you have a VisitorIdentification control in the layouts of your pages?

Comment: @IanGraham yes, I have VisitorIdentification control in the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who might come across the same problem here is the response from sitecore support. This behavior was reported as a bug and as a workaround they suggested to comment out following lines in Sitecore.Analytics.RobotDetection.config:

```
<event name="media:request">
    <handler patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.Analytics.Media.MediaRequestEventHandler, Sitecore.Analytics']" type="Sitecore.Analytics.RobotDetection.Media.MediaRequestEventHandler, Sitecore.Analytics.RobotDetection" method="OnMediaRequest"/>
</event>
```